# Go to URL after OK button if alert is pressed

Tags: javascript, alert, redirect

I need to make sure that when the user clicks OK in a JavaScript alert window, the browser moves to a different URL. Is this possible?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I suspect you mean in a [`confirm`](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php) window (ie. Yes/No options).

```
if (window.confirm('Really go to another page?'))
{
    // They clicked Yes
}
else
{
    // They clicked no
}
```

Answer (score 80):

What do you mean by "*make sure*"?

```
alert('message');
window.location = '/some/url';
```

redirects user after they click OK in the alert window.

Answer (score 20):

An alert does not return a value, in fact returns `undefined` so the easiest way I find right now is conditioning the alert like this

```
if(!alert("my text here")) document.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
```

A better way is using confirm() javascript function like this

```
if(confirm("my text here")) document.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
```

Another option is making your own alert of course

Answer (score 15):

I think what you need is this :

```
if(confirm("Do u want to continue?")) {
    window.location.href = "/some/url"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, simply redirect right after the `alert()` call:

```
alert('blah blah');
location.href = '....';
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is for accessibility and you want to listen to every link on the page and than check if you are leaving the current site to another domain, check out what I wrote, expanding on Joe's answer

```
        $('a').on('click', function() {

            if ( this.host !== window.location.host ) {
                if ( window.confirm('Really go to another page?') ) {
                    // They clicked Yes
                    console.log('you chose to leave. bye.');
                }
                else {
                    // They clicked no
                    console.log('you chose to stay here.');
                    return false
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, reload was also needed.

```
alert('your message');
window.location = '/yoururl';
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Write("<script Response.Write("<script 
language='javascript'>window.alert('Done');window.location='URL';</script>");
```