# change image after ok on alert

Tags: jquery, html

i am clicking on an image and then displaying some message but after click on the ok on alert i want my image to change i am using mvc structure and html is in angular js

i tried like this

```
alert(response);

$('.Opaque_commentWindow_add').addClass('hide');

$(event.target).closest('.contDivs').find('.commentImage').addClass('.display');
```

1.first alert

2.second click on ok the overlay window gets closed

3.but third line doesnt works for changing the image on which  clicked

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394131/go-to-url-after-ok-button-in-alert-is-pressed

Comment: `.addClass('.display');` remove the `.` from `display`.

Comment: Could you please add the HTML code

Comment: why we use .html in jquery

Answer (score 1):

In you posted code, i noticed only this error:

```
$(event.target).closest('.contDivs').find('.commentImage').addClass('display');
//----remove the dot from here---------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[object].style.backgroundImage="url('URL')"
```

where `[object]` is the element of which you want to change the background image.

Comment: you can use the display properties same like that...
[object].style.display="none";