# Alert Box: click ok then pop up a new broswer window to another website, How?

Tags: javascript, popup, alert

javascript like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(!alert("msg here ")) document.location = 'http://google.com';
</script>
```

this scirpt only go to google in a same tab or window, i want to pup up a window then go to google.com.
Thanks.

Comment: try `window.open("http://google.com", "", "width=200, height=100")`

Comment: @TamilSelvan you beat me to it! Docs: [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)

Comment: Also btw duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394131/go-to-url-after-ok-button-in-alert-is-pressed

Comment: I tried, but Chrome block the popup. How to be unblockable? Thanks, Tamil!

Answer (score 0):

The unfriendly way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(!alert("msg here")) window.open("http://google.com");
</script>
```

The more friendly way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(confirm("Do you wish to go to google?")) window.open("http://google.com");
</script>
```

Comment: Disable popup blocker in chrome: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/m-WfaAOYRyA

Comment: thanks, but how to force my vistors to see the popup successfuly? :)

Comment: You can't. There's a reason for popup blockers to exist. You can forse browse to another address, but you can't force to popup a new window. (And even forse browse can be blocked)

Comment: what do you mean force broswer to another address? thats the goal I want to achive. yes, I want force broswer to another address.

Comment: As you did before: window.location.. meaning you use the current window to browse to another address. You can't control a users browser! It's simply wrong to open up a new window without the users consent.

Comment: oh yes. I am too evil. thanks a lot, man. its late in NL, you should get some sleep. :)

Comment: I'm working nightshifts. On topic: There's javascript function called onbeforeunload() which allows you to do stuff if the user closes the browser. What would you think if I force a popup back to my site if you close your browser? Effictively hijacking your browser making it impossible for you to leave my website. No matter what you do, it'll just popup again. Hope you understand the reason behind popup blockers now.

Comment: ah. sorry for the delay. so the function: onbeforeunload() still working for most broswers? Could you write some code for me to use it? like when you close window, popup go to another website. I know it only works for who dont have popup blockers. oh, is popunder same with popup? any popunder blockers exist?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if(!alert("msg here")) window.open("http://google.com");
};
</script>

Comment: Sorry but this is where I draw the line. I don't mind helping with code, but if you intend to do stuff you shouldn't, you're on your own.

Comment: what do you mean? I know nothing about coding, its great if you can help me.