# Redirect after Alert button is clicked - Angular

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I'm building an app in angular and C#.

I'm sending a message (using SignalR) from one user to another.
The message is sent as an Alert (popup window) to the other user, but the problem is that I want to redirect that user (the one who got the message) to another component **after** clicking the **'OK' button on the alert window**.
I don't understand how to bind the button on the alert window to the event in Angular?

Here is my service, where I'm adding the alert message:

```
    public addListenerInvitation(){
    this.hubConnection.on("InvitePlayer", (message: string, sendToUser: 
      string) => {
          this.inviteMsg=message;
          console.log("invitation message: ", this.inviteMsg);
          alert(this.inviteMsg);
      })
    }
```

Comment: Based on Matthieu Riegler answer, maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394131/go-to-url-after-ok-button-if-alert-is-pressed

Answer (score 1):

`alert` is a native function of the browser. It will "block" the thread until the user clicked on okay, so you can consider it as synchronous.

Any code after the `alert()` will run when the user click OK.

Comment: When I'm adding this line code: `this.router.navigateByUrl("/game");` after `alert` I immediately redirect to another component without showing that alert popup window. Does it make sense?